# Return count of processed rows with mysql dynmic query

Tags: mysql, dynamic-sql

I have written a mysql dynamic query to insert data from a database to another database. here is the query.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`Definer1`@`%` PROCEDURE `PushData`()
BEGIN
Set @SqlQuery = 'Insert Into Table_A (Column1,Column2,Column3)
                    Select Column1,Column2,Column3
                    From Table_B
                    Where Table_B.Column1=1;';
PREPARE  Statement From @SqlQuery;
EXECUTE Statement;  
DEALLOCATE PREPARE Statement; 
Select Count(*); -- Count of Inserted Rows
End
```

This Query will send data from Table_B to Table_A. in last i want to return the count of inserted rows.
How do i do it.
I know it is easy when i am not using dynamic query. 
it's just assign the count to a variable and use it with select syntax.
but i have no idea how to do it with dynamic query.
can someone suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return the number of rows affected by an `INSERT` or an `UPDATE` query, use [`ROW_COUNT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count). So replace

```
Select Count(*);
```

with

```
SELECT ROW_COUNT();
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL%rowcount can be used to fetch the number of records inserted. May be below link could be of help.

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2370954?start=0&tstart=0